# JavaScript DOM click handler: added too fast, how to solve without adding a timeout?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a class that represents action to be applied to a fullscreen menu element `this.menu`.

Looks like this (most of the code omitted). Key point is `clickOutsideHandler` listener that will check if `this.menu` contains the event target node: if not, menu should be closed:

```js
class Menu {

  clickOutsideHandler = e => {
    if (!this.menu.contains(e.target)) {
      this.close();
    }
  };

  open() {
    // Apply style changes

    // Add an event listeners
     document.addEventListener('click', this.clickOutsideHandler);
  }

  close() {
    // Revert style changes...

    // Remove event listeners
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.clickOutsideHandler);
  }
}
```

**The problem** here is that `this.clickOutsideHandler` is added "too fast" and even the trigger click get's intercepted by the listener, before actually show the menu:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-menu-trigger]').forEach(trigger => {
   
   trigger.addEventListener('click', e => {
     e.preventDefault();

     // Call open() on the menu instance
     menu.open();
   });
});
```

A small timeout before adding the event listener would solve the problem. What other options do I have?

Comment: can you not check inside your handler if the logic should proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it triggers is because the event is bubbling up the tree until it reaches document which now has the handler.

You could `stopPropagation()` on the event. That way it does not bubble up.

You could also check if the event target is `[data-menu-trigger]` and not close the menu.

EDIT:

Without touching the trigger definition parts, there is not much you can do beside working around it with a timeout... Or is there? A timeout would simply delay the application of the handler to after the event got fully handled. We can change things around by checking if there was a delay between the open and the close request...

By adding a property that stores the current time when the menu is open, and checking against that time when we try to close the menu, you could make sure to close only if 10ms or something elapsed between the two events.

Might not be cleaner or anything, but let's you solve it without adding a timeout and touching the code you don't want to change.

Comment: Yeah, i wasn't clear in my original question. I don't want to "solve" it by the trigger side, but on the menu itself. Guess isn't possible right? Without hardcoding trigger attributes or something

Comment: IMO it is wrong to add part of the handlers from outside the menu and part of them from inside. If it was me, i'd have all event handlers be set by the menu class. With something like a init method that would receive parameters on the query target of the triggers.

Comment: Well, triggers will call open. I could pass the event and that stopPropagation on it, right?

Comment: Right, but that would modify trigger wouldn't it?

Comment: He menu would'n now about the trigger, but only about the event itself. Thanks for the clarification in your answer! I got the idea :)

Comment: It would if you passed a querySelector or an HTMLCollection.